# Anyone seen the 'some' output in playground when using dictonaries?

Tags: swift

I am just writing some simple dictionary code as

```
var picCard: Dictionary<String, Int> = ["jack": 11, "Queen": 12, "King": 13]
```

But when I access one of the entries in the dict in the playground like

```
picCard["Jack"]
```

The output gives me:

```
{some 11}
```

Been through the swift programming guide and cant find out why it says 'some'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is "jack" typo of "Jack"?

The result is correct.

The result of getting the value of the dictionary might be nil, so the type of result is int?(optional with int).
To get the value, you should execute below.

```
picCard["Jack"]! // -> 11
```

Answer (score 4):

Those are optionals. Optional is basically defined like this:

```
enum Optional<T> {
    case None
    case Some(T)
    // ...
}
```

An optional with a value is `Some <value>`, `nil` is `None`:

```
var foo: String = "blah"  // "blah"
var bar: String? = "bleh"   // {Some "bleh"}
```

In your case, subscripting a `Dictionary` returns an optional value, because the key might not exist.